# How to properly re-add a windows administrator user to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently installed SQL Server on a Windows 2008 machine. Down the line the machine was renamed from and when I recently deployed and executed a SSIS package I got the following error message:

The job failed.  Unable to determine if the owner (IP-0AC455TA\Administrator) of job Package has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'IP-0AC455TA\Administrator', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404)).

I assumed this was because of the "old" Administrator name. So logged into SQL Server using the "sa" account and navigated to Security\Logins and removed the IP-0AC455TA\Administrator user. I then re-added the NewName\Administrator account and set it as sysadmin.

This did the trick BUT is it the proper way to do it? I want to make sure that by doing it this way I did not break anything that I don't know of yet. Also, I only created one database on the server and that database is not using any built in administrator accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's certainly how I would've done it - though I always avoid using local users for anything. In my mind, local logins are to get you out of trouble.

Personally, I would have installed everything with a domain admin account and then just added the "Domain Admins" security group.

Or, even better, create a service account.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I don't have a domain setup. But as long as I didn't screw anything up by removing the old admin account and adding a new one I should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, you'll be fine.